# How do I make each box of the Tabs panel coloured when selected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make the individual tab bar light up (or coloured) when each is selected, however, I do not know how to do it. Can someone teach me please?:)

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
});

export default function CenteredTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        centered
      >
        <Tab label="Item One" />
        <Tab label="Item Two" />
        <Tab label="Item Three" />
      </Tabs>
    </Paper>
  );
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: where's your javascript code? do you know how to use javascript?

Comment: @DCR Seems like a strange question. What is shown is standard react JS and JSX code

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in the Material UI React Documentation here: https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/

Click the <> icon to show the full source on the example.

Comment: yes I copied wholesale from Material UI as I needed to change the tab indicator to highlight not only the bottom part of the tab but the whole tab. The examples in material ui only shows  tab indicator highlight on the bottom of the tab (when selected).

Comment: Try to see it's API!